# Use ESAPI Encoder in Java

Tags: java, rest, xss, esapi

The following code shows a Cross site scripting issue in fortify. How can I prevent the same using esapi

```
@POST
@PATH
public EmployeeResponse getFilteredEmployees(EmployeeRequest req, @HeaderParam("user") String user) {
if(user == null) 
   user = req.getEmpId();

EmployeeResponse resp = new EmployeeResponse();
resp.setEmpName(req.getEmpName);
//Do something with the resp

return resp;
}
```

Comment: Also, you're passing the user's name around in the request header.  What are you doing to prevent the user from changing their user to "admin" for your application?

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST
@PATH
public EmployeeResponse getFilteredEmployees(EmployeeRequest req, @HeaderParam("user") String user) {
if(user == null) 
   user = req.getEmpId();

EmployeeResponse resp = new EmployeeResponse();
resp.setEmpName(req.getEmpName);
//Do something with the resp

return resp;
}
```

So, the reason this is getting flagged is that first and foremost, you are not doing any input validation on the variable you're receiving.  Is this a legal userId?  `)>8*2]U5d)s^deUB|SNJRpT7u=: *8SN:$/wapC"C&dW9 R@*aeZFtPUYqfEk`

Because as written, it is.  So is `<script>alert(1);</script>` which is a textbook case of Cross-Site scripting, and `' OR 1=1'` which might cause SQL injection barring a couple other caveats.

Defense 1:  [Input validation.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet)  This is incomplete, but necessary for XSS mitigation.

Defense 2:  Output encoding for the proper context.

On whatever JSP you're using for output, use the ESAPI taglibs, and encode for the [proper context.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

The linked cheat sheets will get you started.  As for code examples, some web frameworks come with input validation APIs, those might suffice, but if using ESAPI you'll add a regex into `validation.properties` and then call that validation rule with the `ESAPI.validator().getValidInput( args... );` call.